# Grid Generating for 4x4 Matrix Function

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a vectors of column sums and row sums and I need to determine prior matrices that made these row sums and col sums. After looking through previous questions, I found this past page that gave me a good head start on this--

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150012/enumerate-all-possible-grids-of-integers-with-constraints

However, my goal is a little different than the code presented above in that I have a 4x3 matrices instead of 3x3 matrices. I attempted to modify the r function to a 4x4 function--I figured I could add a 0 to my sums which would make it easily scalable. The function looks something like this--

```
grid_gen4 <- function(S){
  for(m in unique(combn(rep(0:max(S),16),16,matrix,F,4,4)))if(all(c(rowSums(m),colSums(m))==S))print(m)
}
```

You can see the prior function on the page linked above.

Whenever, I run this function on my first vector

```
c(12,2,3,3,5,4,11,0)
```

I receive an error--

```
Error in vector("list", count) : vector size cannot be NA
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(rep(0:max(S), 16), 16, matrix, F, 4, 4) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

**Any suggestions on how to get around this?**

Also, the code in the prior link runs, but it is a little slow given that I need to do this on hundreds of vectors. I am also curious if anyone has any suggestions on making it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with the `partitions` package:

You don't need to add the extra 0.

```
library(partitions)
findMatrix <- function(target){
cols <- lapply(target[1:3],function(x)compositions(x,4))
grid <- expand.grid(lapply(cols,function(x)seq(ncol(x))))
good <- apply(grid,1,function(x){
  all(rowSums(cbind(cols[[1]][,x[1]],cols[[2]][,x[2]],cols[[3]][,x[3]])) == target[4:7])
  })  
apply(grid[good,],1, function(x)list(cbind(cols[[1]][,x[1]],cols[[2]][,x[2]],cols[[3]][,x[3]])))
}

findMatrix(c(12,2,3,3,5,4,11))
#list()
```

There are no matrices that fulfill these conditions.

Here's an example of a working vector:

```
findMatrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0))
#$`7`
#$`7`[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0
#
#
#$`10`
#$`10`[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0
#[4,]    0    0    0
```

To see how it works, consider the following:

```
compositions(4,4)                                                                        
#[1,] 4 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
#[2,] 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
#[3,] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 1 0
#[4,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

Once we have enumerated all possible columns that add up to a given number, we can use `expand.grid` to iterate through all possible combinations of columns to see if they have `rowSums` that equal our constraint.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Ian! And it actually does work--my columns are just backwards with my rows. It works with c(5,4,11, 12,2,3,3).

Comment: Cool, will do. Thanks!